# how to retrieve docker service communication within a swarm cluster

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-for-windows

docker swarm for windows containers provides any command/option to show communications between containers running on the overlay network?
I'd like to to see the calls sent/handled by specific service instances spread across the nodes on my cluster.
I'm able to push a service on a specific node, see the scaling across nodes, but I'm not able to retrieve information about how often these service instances have been engaged by the docker overlay network.
I do have a service that acts as reverse-proxy to engage all other services within the cluster: I'd like to see how often and which service instances have been called by the reverse proxy. I wonder if docker swarm provides such logs or I do have to use the IIS logging of each services instead.

Answer (score 0):

Overlay networking is just a form of network encapsulation, and won't provide you that higher level information like HTTP calls. For a reverse proxy, the proxies logs are the way to do that (usually turned off by default because they can fill up disks quickly and put more work on the proxy for every request).

If you'd like to see what Swarm and the Nodes are doing in the background in terms of creating containers, networks, running healthchecks, etc. use the `docker events` command on managers and nodes.